# Does GitHub Actions support this non-standard Cron syntax?

Tags: github, cron, github-actions

I saw this on the [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru) website:

[image]

Does GitHub Actions support this syntax? That is, can I define a CI workflow like this?

```yaml
name: "Do something every week"
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "@weekly"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work (yet) because it has an invalid syntax.

> You can schedule a workflow to run at specific UTC times using [POSIX cron syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html#tag_20_25_07). Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or base branch. The shortest interval you can run scheduled workflows is once every 5 minutes.
>
> ...
>
> > **Note**: GitHub Actions does not support the non-standard syntax `@yearly`, `@monthly`, `@weekly`, `@daily`, `@hourly`, and `@reboot`.
>
> [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule)

This can be quickly verified using the GitHub Actions extension on VS Code:

[image]

If you test it on GitHub your workflow will never run, even if you manually trigger it with `workflow_dispatch`.